# Passing parameter to Service injected into another Service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have a service `ApiClientService` which is injected in other Services and Components across my application. For instance it is injected in the `TestService` below.

My `ApiClientService` has a parameter `baseUrl` that can change at injection time

How can I provide the value when injecting it in `TestService` ?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  constructor(private apiClient: ApiClientService) { }
}


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ApiClientService {

   constructor( @Inject('baseUrl') private baseUrl: string) {
   }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean *"when injecting it in `TestService`"*? That's the container's job, the point of DI is that when `TestService` says "I need an `ApiClientService`" it *doesn't* have to know that the `ApiClientService` needs a `baseUrl`, it's *decoupled* from the details.

Comment: TestService could have the need to pass a parameter to ApiClientService, as shown in my example.  In the end I need to do exactly what is described in the following link, only it needs to be done from a service (TestService) instead of  being done from a component :https://www.leonelngande.com/how-i-inject-pass-additional-parameters-into-angular-services/

Comment: Your example does not show that.

Comment: My example shows that ApiClientService takes a parameter based on a injection token. Of course the TestService does not show how to set this token.... because that's the part I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do it, the trick was to create an InjectionToken and provide it at module level.

```
export const API_CLIENT_SERVICE_BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string> ('ApiClientServiceBaseUrl');

  @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
  export class ApiClientService {

  public baseUrl: string;

   constructor() {
      this.baseUrl = inject(API_CLIENT_SERVICE_BASE_URL);
   }

}
```

and in my module :

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: API_CLIENT_SERVICE_BASE_URL,
      useValue: 'some value'
    }
  ]
```

Now in `TestService`, the value of `apiClient.baseUrl` is 'some value'.

Comment: Note you're missing `@Inject`; `string` isn't a valid injection token, there's no connection between the provider and the service. Follow https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-an-injectiontoken-object. It wasn't clear to me what you meant by *"provide the value when injecting it"* - this provides the value *prior* to injecting it, when the container creates the instance.